# Sync between SVN Servers

Tags: svn, repository, visualsvn-server, svnsync

We have a pending takedown of our current Linux-hosted SVN server. So I made a backup to my local Windows PC by doing a **full dump and import/load** to a newly installed VisualSVN server. Let's just say it reached `revision 101`.

So came a few more days and commits in Linux SVN as the unit hasn't been decommissioned. What are my steps to synchronize latest revisions (e.g. `102~110`) with my local VisualSVN server?

I'm still somewhat novice in SVN administration stuff.

Comment: why not migrate to serverfault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I have only checked this command on few samples, it might have edge cases which destroy data. When you have no way to test the integrity of the target repo, you should recreate the target repo with a full dump.]

You can use `svnadmin dump --incremental -r102:110` to create a dump which contains only the revisions 102 to 110. The `--incremental` switch causes to generate a dump, which can be imported into another svn server where the previous revisions are already present.

You can also setup a mirror with [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html).

Comment: Thanks! Although I went with the svnsync method and successfully synchronized them. I suppose I only need to execute the `svnsync synchronize` to get latest updates from now on.